# Android: allow signup with Facebook and store more information

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm working on an android app and I want to allow users to register using Facebook, Gmail etc. 
My question is not how to do that, because there are many posts regarding that including tutorials written by Facebook and Google themselves.

I want to achieve something similar to the Stackoverflow log in - the users are allowed to login using Gmail for instance, while the site (or app) also keeps its own data about each user (namely, my profile).

I'm not quite sure how to achieve something like that in Android, since the Facebook and Google SDK's allow my app to access the user's facebook name, email (and any public information), but I don't think they allow me to add more data about this user my app needs for its own purposes.

What I was thinking of doing is to manage a DB of my own where I could store the additional data (for instance, using Parse.com), and use a common field to all services as a key (was thinking about email, since Facebook, Gmail & twitter all use that - do you recommend this?)

Are there other (better) ways to achieve what I want? perhaps Google offers something I don't know? 
How safe is this (though I should mention that for now the app shouldn't gather any personal information).

As always, any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Store the user's email in your own database along with its session key (don't forget to update it after each login). When the user makes a request to the server **after he logs in** check the email and session key he provides and use them to get his row in the database, where you can store more information about them.

[Regarding Parse.com: They have their own implementation of Facebook login.](https://www.parse.com/facebook)